# Dynamic Table Loader

Tags: c#, file, reader

I have some files which I receive and don't know how many columns and rows I have in those files.
How can I make a generic loader with a generic model where I can always load the file but get different content?

I wrote this but know I know its not always the same table...

```
public override List<Object> getFile(string ab) {

    if (ab == "A") {
        ab = A;
    } else {
        ab = B;
    }
    List<FundPriceModel> models = new List<FundPriceModel>();

    FileStream filestream = new FileStream(ab, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8)) {

        string line;
        bool isHeader = true;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {

            FundPriceModel model = new FundPriceModel();

            if (isHeader) {

                headers = line.Split(spliter[0]);
                isHeader = false;
                continue;
            }
            string[] attributes = line.Split(spliter);

            model.LipperID = IfEmptyInt(attributes[0]);
            model.PriceDate = IfEmptyDateTime(attributes[1]);
            model.PriceCode = safeValue(attributes[2], v => v[0]);
            model.PriceType = safeValue(attributes[3], v => v[0]);
            model.PriceCurrency = safeValue(attributes[4], v => attributes[4]);
            model.PriceValueLC = IfEmptyFloat(attributes[5]);
            model.Estimate = safeValue(attributes[6], v => v[0]);

            Console.WriteLine(model.LipperID + "\t" + model.PriceDate + "\t" + model.PriceCode + "\t" + model.PriceType +
                "\t" + model.PriceCurrency + "\t" + model.PriceValueLC + "\t" + model.Estimate);

            models.Add(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of files? Are they csv? Does the first row contain any information, i.e. header information?

Comment: yes they are csv and are splitted with a \t

Comment: first row has headers always. I HOPE SO!

Comment: are you working on a solution

Comment: If you need to fill specific objects. I think you would need to examine the file headers and determine which of your models the data fits. Then you could use reflection to fill in your models properties.

Answer (score 0):

If a DataTable is generic enough you could use that, its not really a 'Model'. This code is not production worthy and only demonstrates how to load from a CSV.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filePath = @"C:\temp\tesst.csv";
    FileStream filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    DataTable inputTable = new DataTable();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {

        //Get headers and add columns
        string headers = reader.ReadLine();
        foreach (var s in headers.Split(','))
        {
            inputTable.Columns.Add(s, typeof (string));
        }

        //Add rows
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            int colIndex = 0;
            DataRow dr = inputTable.NewRow();
            foreach (var s in line.Split(','))
            {
                dr[colIndex] = s;
                colIndex++;
            }
            inputTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats not the problem. my problem is how to know if its typeof (string) or int or DateTime or something else. how do i know? if i would know a generic way for this i could load it.
btw. is a DataTable usful if you load 4milion rows in it or will it be to much?

Comment: You would have to test loading 4 million rows to check if its a problem. Depends on the amount of data in the rows. Its hard to understand the issue because it sounds like you want to, load an unknown table into a 'Generic' model object. What purpose would this have? You cant know what properties are in 'Generic object' so it wouldn't be useable in any meaningful way besides displaying. If you just want to display then it doesnt matter what the types are. Its really hard to understand what you want accomplish.

Comment: i will get diffrent typ of tables but i dont know what typs the tables have. if the table are loaded i have to start compare them with other tables which should be the same tables but if not the applikation should print out a report sheet for each day.